# sharing view model objects in eclipse RCP without OSGi services

Tags: osgi, eclipse-rcp, datacontext

What is best practice to share light weight view models or data context objects in an Eclipse RCP application, since I do not have control over view creation?  I will prefer not to use OSGi services or static variables for something this light.

Say I have a MapView that will create an instance of its MapViewController in its constructor.

```
public class MapView extends ViewPart  {

    public static final String ID = "myapp.mapview";

    MapViewController controller = null;        

    public MapView() {      

          LegendContainer legends = new LegendContainer();
          MapViewModel viewModel = new MapViewModel();
          controller = new MapViewController(null, legends, viewModel);         
    }

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
           // create main map 


        }
}
```

`MapViewModel` has a property called Legends that needs to be accessed by a `TableOfContentsView` (`TocView`), which is trivial if `TocView` is created as child of `MapView` in `MapView.createPartControl()`

```
@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    // pass model to child here when creating it
}
```

If I want `TocView` and `MapView` to exist as independent views in the perspective, added to the platform in `MapPerspective.createInitialLayout` like this:

```
public class MapPerspective implements IPerspectiveFactory {

@Override
    public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {           

        String editorArea = layout.getEditorArea();             
        layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false);        

        IFolderLayout main = layout.createFolder("right", IPageLayout.RIGHT, 0.2f, editorArea); 
        IFolderLayout top = layout.createFolder("top", IPageLayout.TOP, 0.5f, editorArea); 
        IFolderLayout bottom = layout.createFolder("bottom", IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.5f, editorArea); 



        // how do I share stuff???              
        main.addView(MapView.ID);              
        layout.getViewLayout(MapView.ID).setCloseable(false);

        top.addView(TableOfContentsView.ID);
        layout.getViewLayout(TableOfContentsView.ID).setCloseable(false);

        bottom.addView(PropertiesView.ID);
        layout.getViewLayout(PropertiesView.ID).setCloseable(false);
```

How do I pass around the view model or data context that needs to be shared?

Comment: Services are really the way to go here. Why do you not want to use them?

Comment: I did not think of these type of data objects are services but it appears this is the recommended approach. So how does register and access a service outside of Activator?  Looks like common pattern is to expose the BundleContext via a static member of Activator in the module.

Comment: Activators are evil singletons and should be avoided. If you want to expose/consume services, you should use Declarative Services.

Comment: Thanks for the response and yes I will like to avoid statics.  However Declarative Services looks a lot more cumbersome that simply exposing a static reference to BundleContext in Activator based on this http://www.vogella.com/articles/OSGiServices/article.html#desconsumer, especially when you have many objects to pass around.

Comment: Doing FrameworkUtil.getBundle(MapView.class).getBundleContext().registerService(MapViewModel.class, viewModel, null) also appears simplier than going through declarative services for these simply data objects.

Comment: bnd and its derivatives can generate service-descriptors from annotations for you. My experience is that the initial setup might be a bit more complicated, but later it works really nicely and saves you a lot of trouble.

Comment: You will have to use the Activator or the OSGi API for service lookups from your UI code.  You cannot consume services from views by DS as these objects are not directly constructed by the OSGi runtime, but by the RCP workbench.  There is a disconnect here between RCP and OSGi that you have to fill in yourself (which may be filled in in E4).